# Searching for string that contains escaped characters

Tags: c

I have a binary file that has this particular string in it: `^@^Aname^@Team Fortress 2`

This is how I tried to find it using `memmem`:

```
char *game = "Team Fortress 2";
sprintf(searchString,"\1\1name\1%s\0",game);

...

if(pos = memmem(buffer,result,searchString,strlen(searchString)))
```

How do I match the escaped characters `^@` and `^A`? 
It seems to find `\1\1name`, but not with `game` in `searchString`.

Comment: How could `"\1"` represent both `"^@"` and `"^A"`?

Comment: Control-@ is a null byte, `'\0'` in C (because `@` comes before `A` in ISO 8859-1 and Unicode, etc). `^A` is often used to mean Control-A, byte value `'\1'` or `'\001'`.  Files containing ^@ are usually deemed to be binary files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your string contains nulls it isn't a valid C string and string manipulation functions such as memmem and strlen won't work. You'll have to roll your own version.

The simplest way is to loop through each index of the string, then use a second loop to check it against the string you're searching for. There are fancier and faster methods, but they are more difficult to understand and implement properly if you don't need the extra speed. See [Wikipedia](http://String%20searching%20algorithm) for an overview of the subject.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't caret notation?

```
char *game = "Team Fortress 2";
sprintf(searchString,"%c%cname%c%s\0",(char)0, (char)1, (char)0, game);

...

if(pos = memmem(buffer,result,searchString,strlen(searchString)))
```

Comment: Yes, I realize unfortunately I can't treat it as a string. Since the first character is a null character. `searchString` will have a length of 1.

Comment: so how about write your own or use one of existing memfind? It should be easy.

Comment: @EngieOP The return value of `sprintf` will tell you how many characters were written, so you can use that instead of `strlen`.